# Does rending openni frames require GLUT?

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, glut, openni

I'm not 100% sure on how GLUT renders the data from OpenNI.

I know that GLUT allows an easy creation of a window to contain what's being done between OpenGL <-> OpenNI.

But I was wondering if it was mandatory for me to use GLUT. The application I need to develop will require more than what GLUT has to offer, i.e. I need to make a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Glut is a tool to make setting up a window easier, and most important, portable. It does more, like keyboard/mouse input and various other things, but they are generally not recommended to use.
To answer your question, you can make anything you want without glut, glut just makes some things easier.

Comment: -1: If you're using (Free)GLUT, there's no reason not to use it's keyboard code. You're right in general, but I object to the idea that you shouldn't use GLUT's input code.

Comment: @NicolBolas Where have I stated you "shouldn't use" glut's input code? I just said that is generally not recommended, which is true.

Comment: "*It does more, like keyboard/mouse input and various other things, but they are generally not recommended to use*" Is the "they" in this sentence not meant to mean "keyboard/mouse input and various other things"?

Comment: @NicolBolas Ofcourse "they" means keyboard/mouse input in that sentence, but you seem to fail to understand that "generally not recommended" is something completely different from "shouldn't use". What I mean is that not much people will say "you should use glut's built-in input functions" and that is entirely true, most people that have given me advice about glut in the past told me to use it for window management and nothing more, and I highly doubt this has changed in the last few years.

Comment: I have never heard *anyone* say not to use GLUT's input functions. I've heard people say not to use *GLUT*, but I have never once heard a recommendation that says, "GLUT is fine, but don't use its input functions." Especially since if you don't use theirs, you can't use *anyone else's*, since GLUT doesn't give you access to the HWND to be able to get input yourself.